# How to replace Panel Component with Card Component in React

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I have updated bootstrap from `v3.X.x` to `v4.x.x` and react-bootstrap to `0.32.X` to `1.4.0`, **now I am facing issue with the panel component**.

As per **bootstrap documentation Panel component is removed from latest bootstrap and can be replaced by Card component**.

Anyone help me out to update below **panel component** with **Card Component**

**This is my existing code**:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Panel } from 'react-bootstrap';

<Panel>
    <Panel.Heading style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
        <Panel.Title componentClass="h3" toggle>                                         
            Panel Test
        </Panel.Title>
    </Panel.Heading>
    <Panel.Collapse> 
        <Panel.Body>
           <p> Test Body </p>
        </Panel.Body>
    </Panel.Collapse>
</Panel>
```

`Card.Heading` and `Card.Collapse` is not available at the moment other code we can replace with Card like `Card.Body` or `Card.Title`

Comment: refer the docs dude https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/cards/, its clear enough if not then ask me i'll try and post the code

Comment: Include the code that you have tried with `Card` component and mention what is your problem with it

Comment: @GayatriDipali link helps me get replacement of `Panel.Heading` as `Card.Header` but need code for collapsing as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the components are replaced. For Collapsing I have used `Accordian`

1. `Panel` -> `Card`
2. `Panel.Heading` -> `Card.Header`
3. `Panel.Title` -> `Card.Title`
4. `Panel.Collapse` -> `Accordion.Collapse`

attribute `componentClass` is renamed as `as`

This is final code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Card, Accordion } from 'react-bootstrap';

<Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
    <Card>
        <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} variant="link" eventKey="0" style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
            <Card.Title as="h3" toggle>                                         
                Panel Test
            </Card.Title>
        </Accordion.Toggle>
        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0"> 
            <Card.Body>
                 <p> Test Body </p>
            </Card.Body>
        </Accordion.Collapse>
    </Card>
</Accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry i did not notice that but you can achieve the same effect with react-bootstrap's accordion collapse, you can include that in your card component,
Link to the collapse accordion : https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/accordion/#accordion-collapse-props

Comment: If you have you issues figuring it out then inform me, I'll put up the code